# PHP URL not allowing '+' symbol

Tags: php, laravel, url

I'm using following URL,

```
http://example.com/walkthrough?hostid=abcd&inspectoremail=abc+@gmail.com
```

I get the inspectoremail in a variable like this.

```
$inspectoremail = $_GET['inspectoremail'];
```

BUT when I echo  $inspectoremail, it is replacing '+' symbol by blank space.

```
abc @gmail.com
```

So How can I get inspectoremail as it is specified in the url. 
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `+` has a special meaning in URLs; if you want a literal `+` then urlencode it

Comment: Or, replace back `space` by `+`.

Comment: Yes this worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you pass special characters in the URL you should encode them (using [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) in php).

In your example - the plus (`+`) char is translated to `%2B`, so you should use:

```
http://example.com/walkthrough?hostid=abcd&inspectoremail=abc%2B@gmail.com
```

If you try to encode the space char () you will see that this char will translate to `+`, so when the server decode the string, the value of `abc+@gmail.com` will be `abc @gmail.com` (which is what you got).

Comment: So after encoding, if I echo $_GET['inspectoremail'] , it is the same, + is replaced by white space..!

Comment: How can I encode and then decode the url so that it is reflected in GET method also. ??

Comment: [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode)  / [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode)

Comment: @Aamir, did the answer give you the solution or are you still missing something here?

Comment: I got the solution in @Tom 's comments above. I replaced whitespace by '+'